# Dual booting Windows only works when my Ubuntu disk is disconnected

Tags: dual-boot

I have two internal HDDs connected to a computer. One has 1TB and Windows 7. The other has 160GB and Ubuntu.

When the first boot priority in the bios is the 160 GB Ubuntu disk, Ubuntu works fine. But when I want to boot Windows with its disk as the first priority, it does not boot and a message *Operating system is missing* shows on screen.

When I disconnect the Ubuntu HDD, Windows boots and works fine. I want to be able to boot Windows when both HDDs are connected.

Comment: Are both UEFI or both BIOS? Windows 7 was often BIOS, but could be UEFI. All systems since 2012 and release of Windows 8 are UEFI.

Comment: You can try plug in the disks on the board in different order. It could be that windows sets the Linux disk (or at least one partition on the disk) as `c:` and the windows disk as `d:`, which makes it unbootable, because Windows expects a folder `c:\windows`.